# How to get JasperReports report detail band height?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to hide Detail band 3, if the sum of Detail band 1 and 2 is larger than a certain value. Is it able to make?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a groovy if-statement that does not print the values in the detail 3 values. For example:

```
(($V{var1} +$V{var2}) > 15) ? $F{field1} : null
```

Then you check to not print if null.

Comment: I think you want this in your **print when expression** of your detail band 3 `(($V{var1} +$V{var2}) > 15) ? true : false`

Comment: If you use **print when expression**, then yes. Not if you use it in the text field, however.